# Android Gradle refer assets in code

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have migrated my project to Gradle and now I'm wondering how to refer assets in the code? Apparently code I had doesn't work any more.

In my class that extends SQLLiteOpenHelper, I read a CSV which resides in `src/main/assets/`. Previously I used this

`thisContext.getAssets().open(LOCATIONS_FILE_NAME);`

but that's not OK apparently.

Comment: Gradle has nothing to do with the assets directory.

Comment: Gradle follows the convention over configuration concept, thus the assets should reside in certain directories. This has led me to move my assets.

Comment: If you are talking specifically about android, then it has nothing to do with Gradle. You can access it the same way as it was in Eclipse or ANT

Comment: yes it's Android (as the title and tags imply) but can you provide examples please? Not sure what you mean by Eclipse (the IDE) or Ant (the build tool). I'm looking for the Java syntax.

Comment: My friend, my first comment clearly implies that, your syntax is good, gradle has nothing to do with the accessing of resources of Android. Hope it get it now.

Comment: well then it's strange how the same query returns 0 rows during initialisation. Any ideas?